# Why I use the validateStatus in axios and still can not catch the 404 response that mock.js generate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, mocking

I add the validateStatus to the axios object:

```
const http=axios.create({
    baseURL:'/api',
    timeout: 10000,
    validateStatus: function (status) {
        return status >= 200 && status < 300; // Treat all status codes outside of 2xx as errors
    }
})
```

create get requeset and use mock.js to respond:

```
export const getCurve=(data)=>{
    return http.get('/pageThree/getCurve',{params:data})
}
```

```
Mock.mock(/api\/pageThree\/getCurve/,pages.getCurve)
```

and the pages.getCurve return:

```
export default {
  getCurve: config => {
    console.log(config)

    const urlString = config.url;
    const urlObj = url.parse(urlString);
    const queryParams = queryString.parse(urlObj.query);
    console.log('curve_index', queryParams.curve_index);

    // console.log(curve_index,test_id)
    let results = [];
    let curve1 = [];
    let curve2 = [];
    let curve3 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
      curve1.push(Math.random() * 300)
    }
    results.push(curve1)

    for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
      curve2.push(Math.random() * 500)
    }
    results.push(curve2)

    for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
      curve3.push(Math.random() * 700)
    }
    results.push(curve3)
    console.log(results)
    if (queryParams.test_id == '1234') {
      if (queryParams.curve_index < 2) {
        return {
          code: 200,
          data: results[queryParams.curve_index],
          count_data: 3
        }
      }
      else {
        return {
          status: 404,
          data: results[queryParams.curve_index],
          count_data: 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and when I tried to catch the rejected promise caused by the axios,it turn out that the promise status is still fulfilled since the response was catched by the then()?

```
getCurve(this.test_info).then(({ data }) => {
   console.log('response', data)
}).catch(error=>{
   window.alert(error);
});
```

and the log:

[image]

I wander if it is that I did not generate a right 404 resoponse with mock or it is that I did not use axios the right way ??

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the mockjs actually send a response with status 200,and the 'status' I defined in the mock only add a 'status' prop to the data of the response.And according to the answer :https://github.com/nuysoft/Mock/issues/501#issuecomment-1442677675
I should use mock-server instead.